# Web Scraping NBA.com

Tags: node.js, web, screen-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to return the text found at http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160507/ at this tag

```
 <h4 class="nbaModTopTeamNum  win">95</h4>
```

I am using NodeJS and Cheerio but everytime I console.log the $.text() I get a blank line. 
Here is my code:

```
 1 var request = require('request');
 2 var cheerio = require('cheerio');                                             
 3 var fs = require('fs');                                                       
 4 request('http://www.nba.com/gameline/20160507/', function(err, res,html){     
 5    if(!err && res.statusCode == 200){                                        
 6                                                                              
 7         var $ = cheerio.load(html);                                           
 8         var score = $('h4.nbaModTopTeamNum.win');                             
 9         console.log(score.text());                                            
 10    }                                                                         
 11    else console.log('Error reaching  host');                                  
 12});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the raw HTML source coding from the URL you specified, the `<div>` that matches your selector is empty.  It does not have any content in the raw HTML source.  You can load that URL and then do a View/Source on that page and see that this is the case.

So, apparently the content of that div is filled in by Javascript running in the page which cheerio likely does not run.  So, since you only see the raw HTML source as it originally comes from the server, you are getting no content.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use phantomJS for node, this way you can simulate a [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) browser and make it load the page, then you can use cheerio to scrape the info... Aparently, this is the problem. Here is some phantomJS example, so you can go on and try it: [PhantomJS Scraping example](http://code4node.com/snippet/web-scraping-with-node-and-phantomjs)